# How to get the name of a node in a xml file using xpath/php?

Tags: php, xml, xpath, xmlnode

I have a large xml file and I need to print every entry with a specific namespace and the name of its node (with PHP).

For example, given the following xml structure:

```
    <file>
        <myNamespace:node1>entry1</myNamespace:node1>
        <myNamespace:node2>entry2</myNamespace:node2>
        ... [any other nodes here] ...
    </file>
```

I want to print a tuple of [node1, entry1], [node2, entry2] and so on for every node in the xml file with the myNamespace namespace. The Problem is, I don't know how to get the name of the nodes (the 'node1', 'node2', ...), I only get the entries. For now I'm using this code:

```
    foreach($xml->xpath('myNamespace:*') as $value) {
        echo $value.'<br />';
    }
```

I read something about name() and local-name() function, but I can't get it to work :(
Thank you for helping me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `getName()` - try something like:

```
foreach($xml->xpath('myNamespace:*') as $value) { 
    echo $value->getName().'='.$value.'<br />'; 
}
```